# Prove that $x_0$ is a root of order $k$ of the polynomial $p$ if and only if $p(x_0)=p'(x_0)=\cdots=p^{(k-1)}(x_0)=0\;\text{and}\;p^{(k)}(x_0)\neq 0$

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

> A number $x_0$ is said to a root of order $k$ of the polynomial $p$ provided that $k$ is a natural number such that $p(x)=(x-x_0)^kr(x)$, where $r$ is a polynomial and $r(x_0)\neq0$. Prove that $x_0$ is a root of order $k$ of the polynomial $p$ if and only if $$p(x_0)=p'(x_0)=\cdots=p^{(k-1)}(x_0)=0\qquad\text{and}\qquad p^{(k)}(x_0)\neq 0$$

Proof:

Suppose that $p(x)=(x-x_0)^kr(x)$ where $r$ is a polynomial and $r(x_0)\neq0$. Assume that $p(x_0)=p'(x_0)=\cdots=p^{(k-1)}(x_0)=0$ and $ p^{(k)}(x_0)\neq 0$, the polynomial for $p$ at point $x_0$ is $$p_n(x)=\frac{p^{(k)}(x_0)}{k!}(x-x_0)^k$$ Since $p^{(k)}(x_0)\neq0$, thus, $p(x_0)=0$ which shows $x_0$ is a root of order of the polynomial. Conversely, assume that $x_0$ is a root of order $k$ of the polynomial $p$. Since $p(x)=(x-x_0)^kr(x)$ where $r$ is a polynomial and $r(x_0)\neq0$, the order of $m$ of the polynomial of $p$ at point $x_0$ are equal to $0$ where $0\leq m\leq k-1$. As $x_0$ is a root of order $k$ polynomial, this implies that $p^{(k)}(x_0)\neq0.$

---

Can someone tell me what I need to show? I know that my forward direction isn't right and some mistakes on the reverse direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume $p(x)$ has a root $x_0$ of order $k$. Then $p(x) = (x-x_0)^kr(x)$, and $$p ^{(n)}(x) = \sum_{i = 0}^n \binom{n}{i}((x-x_0)^k)^{(n-i)}r^{(i)}(x) = (x-x_0)^{k-n}q_n(x)$$ for some polynomial $q_n(x)$ whenever $0 \leq n \leq k-1$. This shows that $p(x_0) = p'(x_0) = \cdots = p^{(k-1)}(x_0) = 0$. Moreover we have $p^{(k)}(x) = \sum_{i = 0}^k \binom{k}{i}((x-x_0)^k)^{(k-i)}r^{(i)}(x)$, which shows that $p^{(k)}(x_0) = k!r(x_0) \neq 0$.

Conversely, if $p(x_0) = 0$, by the division theorem for polynomials we must have $p(x) = (x-x_0)q_1(x)$ for some polynomial $q_1(x)$. Then $p'(x) = q_1(x) + (x-x_0)q_1'(x)$, and so the condition $p'(x_0) = 0$ yields $q_1(x_0) = 0$. Thus $q_1(x) = (x-x_0)q_2(x)$ for some polynomial $q_2(x)$, and so $p(x) = (x-x_0)^2q_2(x)$. Keep doing this until you get $p(x) = (x-x_0)^kq_k(x)$, where $q_k(x_0) \neq 0$ because of the hypothesis $p^{(k)}(x_0) \neq 0$.

Comment: I want to know how do know the $nth$ differentiation of $p(x)$

Comment: @Simple It's a straightforward generalization of the product rule. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule#Higher_derivatives) for instance.